# Reactive Cocoa for Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, reactive-cocoa, carthage

I am updating a project from Swift 2.x to 3.0. I have `ReactiveCocoa` version v4.2.2  installed via Carthage. To update reactive cocoa I have updated my cart file as

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "master"
```

When I run command `Carthage update`, it gives the following error in terminal:

> No tagged versions found for github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the github link is wrong.

github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift" "master"

Comment: Tried above link, same error( github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift" "master")

*** Fetching ReactiveSwift
No tagged versions found for github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift"

Answer (score 0):

Following link helped sove the issue

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases/tag/0.15.1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "5.0.0-alpha.1"
```

it's an official release for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'targetName' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'ReactiveCocoa', :git => 'https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
    pod 'Result', :git => 'https://github.com/antitypical/Result.git', :tag => '3.1.0'
  end

  post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```